# How do you rename a textfile with a datetime stamp in php?

Tags: php

I'm new to php and programming in general, so forgive my ignorance on this one.  I am trying to rename a textfile I created with a datetime stamp, and can't seem to get it right.  I am writing info to a textfile after someone submits data, and that works, but I need to make every text file unique, so I need a unique naming convention.  I even tried using the first name of the entry, but I can't get that to work either.  Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
$FirstName = $_POST["fname"].PHP_EOL;
$LastName = $_POST["lname"].PHP_EOL;
$Address = $_POST["address"].PHP_EOL; 
$City = $_POST["city"].PHP_EOL; 
$State = $_POST["st"].PHP_EOL; 
$Zip = $_POST["zip"].PHP_EOL; 
$Tel = $_POST["tel"].PHP_EOL; 

$AddressFile = "Address_Entries.txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($AddressFile, "a") or die("can't open file");

$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

fwrite($ourFileHandle, $FirstName);
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $LastName);
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $Address);
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $City);
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $State);
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $Zip);
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $Tel);
fclose($ourFileHandle);
echo "<p>File has been writtten to successfully!</p>";

rename("C:/xampp/security/htdocs/testes/Address_Entries.txt", $FirstName);
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

- A

Comment: Where is exactly your file date timestamp?

Comment: ...and what happens if I put `/boot.ini` into the FirstName field?

Comment: I get it through the $date variable, but I haven't been able to use that in combination with rename().  The echo statement prints on the page for DateTime(), but I'm clueless how I can get that stamp to be my file name...

Answer (score 0):

If you need a unique ID to name files with, try [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/uniqid)

Answer (score 0):

In windows you must use correct path:

```
rename("C:\\xampp\\security\\htdocs\\testes\\Address_Entries.txt", "C:\\xampp\\security\\htdocs\\testes\\$FirstName.txt");
```

Comment: Forward slashes work fine on Windows, just about everywhere other than command prompt. They even work in the address bar in explorer.

Answer (score 0):

This will rename the file using the timestamp. But a unique naming convention, this has a great chance to be unique, but is NOT unique. If someone was to post at the very same time... with the same first name... you'll have duplicate files.

Now is it a big chance? No.

```
<?php
$file = '/tmp/this-is-temp-file.txt';
$firstName = 'BeepBeep';
$timestamp = time();
rename($file, '/path/to/new/file/'.$firstName.'-'.$timestamp.'.txt');
?>
```

Possibly try to incorporate a uniqid() function. I don't think it is unique again as it uses time() (I think)... but may be better off padding it with a unique counter (like an ID from the database)

This assumes:
a) You have access to the FULL PATH
b) PHP has access to the file! You might be able to WRITE the file, but maybe not enough permissions to move, delete, rename, edit..

Comment: @PiotrOlaszewski It will... Just try it. Obviously the paths have to be valid, but drive letters are not required (use current working volume if missing) and forward slashes work just fine.

Comment: thanks for the help all, but I wasn't able to get the timestamp to work out.  Kind of interesting that I was able to make the uniqid() to work, but couldn't get this to change the name.  I kept getting this error:

Comment: Warning: rename(C:/xampp/security/htdocs/testes/Address_Entries.txt,asd ) [function.rename]: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (code: 123) in C:\xampp\security\htdocs\testes\Saved_Record.php on line 87

Comment: rename(C:/xampp/security/htdocs/testes/Address_Entries.txt,asd ) is your issue. First, I believe the warning should show full path with quotes. Make sure it is:

rename("C:/xampp/security/htdocs/testes/Address_Entries.txt", "")

The other aspect that raises a flag to me is the ,asd) part. It should show the variable's value if I'm not mistaken. Make sure the variable is actually a variable.

Comment: @CrazyVipa, asd is actually the text I typed in the field for testing, so it did grab that part, it just didn't rename the textfile.  This is the variable that it is using:  $FirstName = $_POST["fname"].PHP_EOL;

Comment: Ah, then that is the error. The rename function needs an absolute path to work. So the 2nd variable would need a "C:/xampp/security/htdocs/user_data/__uniqid_value.txt"

Comment: No dice - still tryin':  rename("C:/xampp/security/htdocs/testes/Address_Entries.txt", "C:/xampp/security/htdocs/testes/".$date->format('Y-m-d_H:i:sP').".txt")

Comment: Try setting the date to a $var = $date->format('Y-m-d_H:i:sP'). But also... (not sure if it matters at all) but your colon (':') is invalid for a windows file name. Remove or replace those to a - or _

Comment: @CrazyVipa, thanks for all the help - totally worked.  I think it was the colon.  I changed it to $date->format('Y-m-d_His') and removed the "P".  You're awesome.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help. Should mark this as the answer and close it out. :)